# How to assign account to Teamviewer 15 on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-buster

I am trying to install Teamviewer on raspberry pi solely via command prompt. The installation completed successfully and I could assign a password. However, it could not perform [teamviewer setup] step where I have to enter my teamviewer account email and password. I got the messages:

**1. Device is not assigned to an account. Please run interactive setup.**

**2. You have to be root to add this device. Setup cannot continue and will exit now.**

Even in root (sudo su), i cant get this to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved installing the previous version of teamviewer. now it works fine.

First completely remove the old version prompting

```
    sudo apt purge teamviewer
```

and then get the previous version of teamviewer from the web

```
    wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/version_13x/teamviewer-host_armhf.deb
```

now you can install this version typing

```
    sudo apt install ./teamviewer-host_armhf.deb
```

and check if it is the #14 version by typing

```
    teamviewer version
```

now you can link your raspberry to your account simply typing

```
    sudo teamviewer setup
```

without entering the password before

Comment: Something weird is going on...i can't explain it. The first time I tried your suggestion, it works. Second time trying it, the error **You have to be root to add this device. Setup cannot continue and will exit now.** comes out again...any ideas?